# PayPal pre-approved payment button

Tags: javascript, java, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to implement the paypal pre-approve functionality (obtained through the Adaptive Payment API) in our crowdfundig platform. At the click of the paypal pay buton button my back-end generates the pre-approve key and SHOULD redirect the user to the appropriate PayPal link:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-preapproval&preapprovalkey=GENERATED_PRE_APPROVE_KEY
```

I am currently using the classic checkout button (checkout.js) which does not seem configurable to be redirected to another type of PayPal address (it just redirect to the standard payment url and not the pre-approve). What should I do? Create a custom button? Or can I change the behavior of a classic PayPal button?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer to my own question. After the generation of the pre-approval key, what I did was redirecting the user from the current page to a new one to this link :

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-preapproval&preapprovalkey=GENERATED_PRE_APPROVE_KEY
```

In order to redirect the user to a new window I used the standard :

```
window.open(linkWithPreApprovalKey);
```

It seems that ther's no specific pre-approval or adaptive payment button made by PayPal (such as checkout.js for a normal checkout)